# Eclipse C programming Multi thread- data transfer between threads

Tags: c, multithreading, queue

I have being trying Multi threading on Eclipse with linux real time target.
I have two threads which will be doing these functions implemented with p thread.

Thread-1
-Communicate with hardware and acquire 1000 samples in a second , collecting 100 sample per cycle, ie thread will be running 10 times in a second. data type is double.

Thread-2
this thread will be analyzing data from first thread, like filtering smoothing and logging to a file.

I need to transfer data from first thread to second thread via queue, i will  enqueue from first thread and dequeue from second thread

how can i achieve this?, can i enqueue and dequeue at the same time?
where can i find example for this?

Thank You

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Eclipse is an IDE btw and is really unrelated here

Comment: sounds like your bog-standard producer-consumer problem.

Comment: Normally have a mutex on updating the queue pointers.

Comment: Im in  the design level, i need to know if there is any ready made library for queue (Like p thread for threads) or i have to implement it with datatypes.

Comment: Yes im doing the same producer consumer loop

Comment: i need to insert data to queue as well as take data from thread(on the second thread) simultaneously, that why im planing for a producer consumer loop, and threads will be running on a real time system, so cant accept any delay